# React JS: написать тройной if

Tags: reactjs, if

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение. Дано:

```
var mode = item.image_height > item.image_width ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

var mode = item.image_height = item.image_width ? 'square' : 'square'
```

Как объединить эти две строки в один if?

Если width больше height то landscape, а если меньше то portrait, а если ровно то square

Answer (score 3):

Вот так.

P.S.: Советую сокращать длинные названия в новые переменные, как в примере, для лучшей читабельности:

```
var w = item.image_width;
var h = item.image_height;

//ECMAScript
var mode = (w === h)

   ? 'square' 
   : (w > h) 

       ? 'landscape'
       : 'portrait';

//Эта же конструкция на нативном JavaScript (мб так понятнее)
var mode;

if (w === h) { 

   mode = 'square'; 

} else if (w > h) { 

   mode = 'landscape'; 

} else {

   mode = 'portrait';

}
```